# Check if string contains only permitted characters

Tags: ruby, regex, string

The task: Identifiers must contain at least one non-digit AND only contain digit, letter, "_", and "-" characters.

Therefore 'qwerty', 'identifier-45', 'u_-_-', '-42-' are valid identifiers.

And '123456', 'w&1234', 'identifier 42' are invalid.

**Can I achieve this with a regular expression.**

```
id.match(/\w\d/)
```

Or with more than one match

```
id.match(/\w/) &&  id.match(/\d/)
```

**Or may be I would make an array of all permitted characters and filter the original string removing them (if the rest is more than [], there are forbidden ones)?**

```
id.to_a.select{|character| !((0..9) + (a..z) + ['-','_']).include?(character)}.count == 0
```

i.e. all permitted characters are excluded from the string, and if its length is more than 1, there would be some forbidden characters (like **&**)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using positive lookahead:

```
pattern = /^(?=.*\D)[-\w]+$/

pattern =~ 'qwerty'
# => 0
pattern =~ 'identifier-45'
# => 0
pattern =~ 'u_-_-'
# => 0
pattern =~ '-42-'
# => 0

pattern =~ '123456'
# => nil
pattern =~ 'w&1234'
# => nil
pattern =~ 'identifier 42'
# => nil
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use lookahead to implement your rules:

```
/^(?=.*\D)[\w-]*$/
```

This regex will only match strings with at least one non-digit, containing only alphanumerical characters (not accentuation though), `_` and `-`.